# How do I consolidate all this jQuery code into an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I'm making a game that uses sixteen cards (eight pairs of two matching cards each, so there are eight corresponding CSS classes). I think my code would be much easier to maintain and much cleaner if I could consolidate it. I figured I could do this using arrays, but I'm not quite sure how I would do that. I started doing it at the top (I made an array variable cardArray and started to make a for loop, but commented it out). Here's all my code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 0;
        var cardArray = ['yinyang', 'heart', 'star', 'smiley', 'peace', 'crescent', 'target', 'swirl'];

        /*for(var i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++){
        }*/

        $('.click').click( function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('flip');
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);

            // if two cards have been flipped:
            if (counter == 2) {

            // the following code checks to see if any matching pairs have been selected:

                if($("#yinyang-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#yinyang-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#yinyang-02").hasClass("click") && $("#yinyang-01").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both yin yangs!");
                    $("#yinyang-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#yinyang-02").removeClass('click');

                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#heart-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#heart-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#heart-01").hasClass("click") && $("#heart-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both hearts!");
                    $("#heart-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#heart-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#star-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#star-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#star-01").hasClass("click") && $("#star-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both stars!");
                    $("#star-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#star-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#smiley-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#smiley-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#smiley-01").hasClass("click") && $("#smiley-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both smileys!");
                    $("#smiley-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#smiley-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#peace-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#peace-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#peace-01").hasClass("click") && $("#peace-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both peace signs!");
                    $("#peace-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#peace-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#crescent-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#crescent-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#crescent-01").hasClass("click") && $("#crescent-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both crescents!");
                    $("#crescent-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#crescent-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#target-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#target-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#target-01").hasClass("click") && $("#target-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both targets!");
                    $("#target-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#target-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                else if($("#swirl-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#swirl-02").hasClass("flip") && $("#swirl-01").hasClass("click") && $("#swirl-02").hasClass("click")){
                    console.log("you got both swirls!");
                    $("#swirl-01").removeClass('click');
                    $("#swirl-02").removeClass('click');
                    counter = 0;
                    console.log(counter);
                }

                // if none of the matching pairs have been selected, flip all the cards back:
                else {
                    console.log("try again!");

                    if($("#yinyang-02").hasClass("click") && $("#yinyang-01").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#yinyang-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#yinyang-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#heart-01").hasClass("click") && $("#heart-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#heart-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#heart-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#star-01").hasClass("click") && $("#star-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#star-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#star-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#smiley-01").hasClass("click") && $("#smiley-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#smiley-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#smiley-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#peace-01").hasClass("click") && $("#peace-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#peace-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#peace-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#crescent-01").hasClass("click") && $("#crescent-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#crescent-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#crescent-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#target-01").hasClass("click") && $("#target-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#target-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#target-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    if($("#swirl-01").hasClass("click") && $("#swirl-02").hasClass("click")){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#swirl-01").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#swirl-02").removeClass('flip');
                        }, 600);
                    }

                    counter = 0;
                }

            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a loop is right .. it's fairly simple since you can concatenate the selector.

```
if (counter == 2) {
    cardArray.forEach(function (card) {
        if ($("#" + card + "-01").hasClass("flip")
            && $("#" + card + "-02").hasClass("flip")
            && $("#" + card + "-02").hasClass("click")
            && $("#" + card + "-01").hasClass("click")
        ) {
            /* snip */
        }
    });
}
```

This would be the bulk of your consolidation, but you can probably consolidate further by changing the selector:

```
$("[id^='" + card + "'].flip.click").length === 2
```

Comment: Is "card" the name you gave to each element in the array? Also, since there's only one "if" statement and seven "else ifs," do I need to declare the if statement first and then loop only through the else ifs?

Comment: @ArielCotton 1) yes it is. 2) I guess you could wrap the whole thing in a loop

Comment: Explosion Pills, it's not working. I implemented your code and it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( " in the console.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Sorry, I guess I missed that.